# HKQueryAnchor Becomes Invalid After App Reinstallation

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'm developing an iOS application that uses HealthKit and leverages HKQueryAnchor for fetching incremental updates to avoid pulling the entire dataset each time. This method works well until the app is deleted and subsequently reinstalled.

Post-reinstallation, when I restore a previously saved HKQueryAnchor and use it in an anchored query, it behaves as though no anchor was passed, returning the entire dataset instead of incremental updates. This issue seems to arise solely after an app has been deleted and reinstalled; HKQueryAnchor functions as expected if the app is not removed.

I anticipated that restoring and utilizing the HKQueryAnchor, even after deleting and reinstalling the app, would allow the application to continue from where it left off before deletion, fetching only new HealthKit data entries.

Is this assumption wrong? or am i missing something?

Comment: The behaviour you describe sounds reasonable to me. If the app is deleted, all of its data is deleted, so iOS can't tell the difference between a reinstallation and a first time installation, and even if it could, presumably the data you had previously fetched would no longer be available so you need to start from scratch.

Comment: Upon reinstalling the app, I retrieve the HKQueryAnchors and all necessary data from the backend once the user logs in, aiming to restore the app to its previous state before deletion. Would this approach still encounter the same problem?

Comment: iOS doesn't know that you have stored the data on your server and I would not expect query anchors to be valid across devices, so there is little point in storing them on your server. They should be stored in the device and a reinstall will be the same as a first time install

Comment: Thanks, Paulw11. Appreciate the info.